# Authenticate registering users against already existing User profiles on Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am busy with a Web Api 2 project in VS 2013. We have a number of established applications, and a couple hundred clients with in turn thousand's of users registered at each client.

I am assigned with creating a Mobile App (Cordova/Phonegap), but before I can do this I need to create an API that can handle http Requests from the app.

We have a large database with 173 tables including a user table. This database exists at each client (with their own users). I have imported the default AspNet... tables into our database, changed the connection string and have successfully managed to register users on our database.

[image: AspNet default tables]

**My questions is this:** Is it possible add additional registration requirements? e.g. in addition to Email, Password, (ConfirmPassword), I'd like to add:

1) Mobile Number

2) Identity number

so that they are also written to AspNetUsers, and then **somehow create a foreign key link to my existing USERS table, let's say on ID number provided by the user?**

The idea is to not let any user register with the **mobile APP** that is not already registered on the database.

So, how it should be able to work in my head is not necessarily correct, but here is a summary below:

1) User download app from app store. 
2) App shows register/login screen, user register with **Email, password, ConfirmPW, MobileNr, ID** 
3) App sends HTTPS Post request to API with above info. 
4) API gets info, before binding to model and writing to db, first does a query to existing User table. If a user exists with ID and mobile Number, then AspNetUsers record is created (with FK reference to Users table). If not, user is not allowed to register, and message is returned, e.g. You need to be a Client of "CompanyName" to register. 
5) After this, user logs in and uses Bearer token etc. (default log in way).

I know this is not necessarily how it will work in practice, but can something like this be done. I don't want to re-invent any wheel, only add what listed above. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using ASP.Net Identity 2?

Comment: @su8898, from References, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, check properties, it says version 2.0.0.0. This is a standard Web API 2 project in VS 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can customize the User information. You need to customize the `IdentityUser` class. [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) is a great tutorial on how to do it. I even managed to change the normal Id in the AspNetUsers table (which is nvarchar by deault) to an int.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a shot @su8898. Thanks for the awesome tutorial. Seemed to be lost without this.